# Logical XOR and NULL checks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this check constraint,

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_VerboseXNOR] CHECK
    (([A] IS NULL AND [B] IS NULL) OR ([A] IS NOT NULL AND [B] IS NOT NULL))
```

it asserts that either `A` and `B` are both `NULL` or that both are not `NULL`. What you may consider an [XNOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) operation.

Is there a more succinct way to write this in TSQL that avoids the double use of each term.

---

Ideally I'd like this (you can't stop me dreaming.)

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_SuccinctXNOR] CHECK ([A] IS NULL XNOR [B] IS NULL)
```

---

**Edit**

I have tried

```
CHECK (CASE WHEN [A] IS NULL THEN [B] IS NULL ELSE [B] IS NOT NULL END)
```

Which looks like just three evaluations but, it doesen't work (won't parse).

I haven't tried

```
CHECK (IIF([A] IS NULL, [B] IS NULL, [B] IS NOT NULL))
```

and given the failure of above, I'm not optimistic enough to try.

I can't quite get my head around how `CHECK` can accept a logical expression but `CASE` (and perahps `IIF`) cannot return one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNOR is just equals. XOR is not equals.

Because there is no boolean type in T-SQL (for no good reason) we have to abuse integers:

```
WHERE
 (CASE WHEN [A] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 = (CASE WHEN [B] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Not pretty either.

Martin's variant is slightly better:

```
WHERE IIF(A IS NULL, 0, 1) = IIF(B IS NULL, 0, 1)
```

I usually use the form that you have written in your question. The optimizer recognizes this form (for example for index seeks) but it does not recognize the integer-based form.

Comment: A slightly more concise variant is `DECLARE @T TABLE (A INT,B INT,CHECK (IIF(A IS NULL,0,1) =  IIF(B IS NULL,0,1)))`

Comment: @MartinSmith, usr, I'v added flesh to the question. Any further information gratfully received.

Comment: @Jodrell you're trying to use boolean expressions as values of a boolean type. T-SQL does not have a boolean type. `0=0` has no type. You can only use it in places that the T-SQL grammar explicitly called out. (Yes, this is not useful behavior.)

Comment: @usr It's just a forlorn hope. I was hoping a logical closure/delegate might be curriable, since some constructs require such.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a function that does your XNOR and calling that in your constraint?

I have never down this myself, but google popped up: [Check Constraints That Call Functions](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2011/08/08/check-constraints-that-call-functions/)

Comment: I could but I'm worried that what I'd save in typing I'd lose in performance.

Comment: Dare I mention the `p` word???  As in `profile`.  I have no idea whether using a function is a good or bad thing to do.